# Setting a variable cost in Stripe payment gateway on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model-associations, stripe-payments

I have set up Stripe on Rails, and it is working as anticipated.

I have three models that pertain to an order.  A User model, a Course model, and an Order model.  They are associated through a has_many association.
When a user purchases a course the order table is updated with the User ID and Course ID.

What I can not figure out is **how to NOT hard code the price into the Stripe request and Create Method**. The course model has a **:cost** variable and I would like to set the cost by calling @course.cost.  I can't seem to be able to get this to work.

Here is my order model:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :stripe_card_token, :course_id, :user_id
    attr_accessor :stripe_card_token
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
    belongs_to :course
    belongs_to :user

    def save_with_payment
        @amount = 500
        if valid?
            charge = Stripe::Charge.create(amount: @amount, currency: 'usd', card: stripe_card_token)
            #self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
            save!
        end
        rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
        logger.error "Stripe error while creating customer: #{e.message}"
        errors.add :base, "There was a problem with your credit card."
        false
    end
end
```

And my order Controller:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

    def new
      @order = Order.new
    end
    def create
      @order = Order.new(params[:order])
        if @order.save_with_payment
           redirect_to @order, :notice => "Thank you for your purchase!  Enjoy your Class!"
           else
           render :new
       end
    end
    end
```

Comment: `self.course.cost` ? why the `@` ?

Comment: When I use self.course.cost I get this error:  wrong number of arguments (1 for 0).

Comment: sorry....this is the error I am getting:  Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured I would post the answer to this if anyone else comes across it.

In the order controller:

```
def save_with_payment

    @amount = self.course.cost

    if valid?
        charge = Stripe::Charge.create(amount: @amount, currency: 'usd', card: stripe_card_token)
        #self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
        save!
    end
```

The part that I left out was correctly nesting the resource in routes.rb:

```
resources :courses do
 resources :orders
end
```

And finally in my controller:

```
def new
    @course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
    @order = @course.orders.new

end
```

This works like I need it to, though if anyone else has a better method I am more then open to suggestions! :)